# Selectable Jquery and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, selectable

I'm looking for a way to send the selected items to a selectable of Jquery to a php page

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
      stop: function() {
        var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
        $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
          var index = $( "#selectable li" ).index( this );
          result.append( " #" + ( index + 1 ) );
        });
      }
    });
  });

  $(function() {
    $("#foo").submit(function(event){
        $.post('batch.php?page=rinomina', {selectable: $('#select-result').html()});
    });
  });
  </script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $( ".direct" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {

      });
  });
  </script>

<form id="foo" action="" method="post">
    <a href="javascript:{}" class="direct"onclick="document.getElementById('foo').submit(); return false;">submit</a>
```

but it is wrong and do not understand where I'm wrong!

Comment: `$.post('batch.php?page=rinomina', {selectable: $('#select-result').html()});` is not passing your selected's, it's passing the entire HTML written inside of element with id `select-result`

Comment: I think what you're trying to get is checkboxes? Or do you really want to pass all the HTML? Need a better understanding of want you want PHP to recieve

Comment: selecting one or more elements get # 1 # 2 # 3 ...
in php I want a simple variable that contains these 3 values​​. I added. html only because it was suggested to me to so. What do I do?

Comment: I see, sounds like what you really want is a list of Checkboxes with the Selectable design. There are quite a few different ways to go about this, none extremely simple. However, none very hard either. [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) Will prep your elements for POST to the PHP, however I think what you want are the indexes, correct?

Comment: right, but I do not know how to do

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I fully understand. What it appears you want is the index number of each selected list item to send as a parameter to a php method?  You could go about this in many ways. The easiest I can think of with what you have would be to get the indexes of the selected, then use jQuery's param method to make them URL friendly and add to your post url. For example:

## Example

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectable").selectable();

    $("#foo").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ids = new Array();
        $("#selectable .ui-selected").each(function(i) { ids[i] = "# " + ($(this).index()+1); });

        // get values as URL parameters for passing to PHP
        var paramSelectable = $.param({ selectable: ids });

        //    easiest implementation with what you have
        $.post('batch.php?page=rinomina&'+paramSelectable);
    });
})
```

Comment: does not work: (The original page has batch.php, clicking on the button to submit the form with id "foo", redirects to batch.php?